# UIButton image not changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I have 4 `UIButtons` that I want to flash a lighter colour image for one second in a random sequence. So obviously I want to change the buttons images programatically. As you can see in the  [XCode Project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u21t1nkhyp0vtwn/UhVsOB3n-m) method: showSequence, it tries to set the image to the lighter one, then back again, but it doesn't show on the simulator.

Code Snippet:

```
- (void) showSequence:(NSMutableArray *)sequenceArray {

    for(int i = 0; i < [sequenceArray count]; i++){

        int sequenceNumber = [[sequenceArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        switch (sequenceNumber) {
           case 1: {
              NSLog(@"green");
              [self.greenButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              sleep(1);
              [self.greenButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              break;
           }

           case 2: {
              NSLog(@"red");
              [self.redButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              sleep(1);
              [self.redButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              break;
           }

          case 3: {
             NSLog(@"yellow");
             [self.yellowButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             sleep(1);
             [self.yellowButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             break;
          }

          case 4: {
             NSLog(@"blue");
             [self.blueButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             sleep(1);
             [self.blueButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             break;
        }

        default:
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance (btw, dont tap the start button during the sequence it will break (im still working on it))

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by simply adding imageView to Button & assign NSArray to imageView.animationImages property. NSArray must contain the images as per your sequence 
see below code

```
 imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame1.gif"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame2.gif"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame3.gif"],
                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageFrame4.gif"], nil];


        imageView.animationDuration = 2.0; 
        imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // for showing only once, otherwise set to 0
        [imageView startAnimating]; 
[self.button addsubView:imageView]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, but how can i get it to not repeat the animation?

Comment: simply add 1 here imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Check

1. Images added and named correctly
2. See if image is added on button,then background image is not visible.
3. IBoutlets are connected
4. Instead of `setBackgroundImage:` Try `setImage:`

Comment: when you click on the button this code get executed? check with a breakpoint